# What is the word that best suits this context?

Tags: word-request

I was telling my colleague that a project name cannot be generic (which cannot be easily created on our own). I meant to say the name should follow some standards.

Now could you please tell me whether it is correct to use the word generic here? If not, what else can I use?

Comment: You're using *generic* to mean "does not follow [= conform to] any standards"?

Comment: Is "Casual" what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that the choice of name must follow some specific rules? Or do you mean that the name must not be an ordinary word, but must demonstrate some imagination? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant that it needed to comply with some standards, or that some other department is responsible for assigning a name, you might say that it can't be ['ad-hoc'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc) or ['improvised.'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improvised)

If you wanted to speak in the positive about the project name, you could say that your project names are ['regulated'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regulated) or ['constrained'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constrained) by these rules.

If this is not helpful, please re-word your question to add either more detail, or an example of the conversation to add context.

Comment: My guess is that your guess as to what OP is trying to ask is correct. So your *ad-hoc, improvised,* Damkerng's *arbitrary* and alternatives such as *unconventional* would all be acceptable. Most likely, OP has misunderstood the meaning of *generic*.

Comment: @MrWondrful and FumbleFingers: Thank you both of you.

Comment: I thought Generic means common or not specific. But the words improvised and arbitrary really suites. thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to suggest another word: **arbitrary**.

> **[arbitrary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arbitrary)** (adj.)
>   based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system.

Comment: +1 Yes, that's the word I was racking my brain for when I answered.  I almost mentioned "willy-nilly," but then thought better of it.  Thanks!